# command prompt display "This should not be &"

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

When I open CMD, display "This should not be &."

[image: The screenshot]

I tried to look for "&" in the environment variable, but nothing here

[image: The screenshot]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does the same issue exist in the new window when you type `start cmd /d` in that one?

Comment: @Compo It worked. There were no errors.

Comment: Good, now we just need to fine tune the appropriate permanent fix for it, what happens when you open a new Command Prompt window, `cmd` using the `Run as administrator` option?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, based upon the answers you've supplied in your comments, is that you have a rogue entry in your registry. Your response to my initial comment is not really a permanent fix, for anything, I only used that to determine what your issue was.

As you've not yet replied to second comment I have not been able to determine the exact location of that entry. For that reason I will offer two possible solutions.

If when you open a new Command Prompt window, `cmd`, using the <kbd>Run as administrator</kbd> option, the issue is not there, then copy and paste the following, then press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V AutoRun /F >NUL
```

If the issue still exists when you opened using the <kbd>Run as administrator</kbd> option, copy and paste the following, then press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /V AutoRun /F >NUL
```

Your issue should now be permanently resolved.